# adding swagger to WCF

Tags: wcf, swagger

I am trying to make a proper nice documentation for a Microsoft WCF.
I added an asp web app to display swagger and installed
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.5.6.3

I've set the solution to run both the WSF service and the asp web app.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace asp_core_webapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Version = "1.0", Description = "my api " });
                c.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));
                c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddControllers();

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I do no see anything running on
/swagger/v1/swagger.json
/swagger/v1
/swagger

There does not seem to be any valid documentation out there.
Any ideas how to make swagger work?
If you know another better alternative to Swagger, please feel free to add comments.
thanks

update: this is the main part of my config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="serviceEndPoint" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved?

Comment: Hi, I tried a lot of things and updated my config above. It is still not working.

Comment: If you use webhttpbinding, you also need to add [WebInvoke] to the operation agreement. For more information about webhttpbinding, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Ho. No. I never made it work.

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net Core does not fully support WCF, if Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.5.6.3 is a package in AspNetCore, it may not be supported in WCF. In fact, WCF also has its own help document, you only need to enable it in the configuration file:

```
   <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. /service1.svc/help does not exit. Also tried service1/help.

Comment: What is your configuration file? This is related to your endpoint address.

Comment: Add /help after the service base address.

Comment: I posted my web.config. Can you post and example for your last comments please?

Comment: I see that you are using basicHttpsBinding, but the help document is only for webhttpbinding.